# Как открыть случайную картинку из каталога?

Tags: windows, bat

В папке есть картинки и текстовые файлы. Как открыть случайную картинку?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Считаем число подходящих файлов в каталоге
2. Генерируем случайное число - индекс открываемого файла
3. Находим файл с соответствующим индексом
4. Открываем его

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set n=0
for %%f in (*.jpg, *.jpeg, *.gif, *.png) do set /a n+=1
echo Total files %n%

set /a i = %RANDOM% %% n
echo Going to open %i%

set q=0
for %%f in (*.jpg, *.jpeg, *.gif, *.png) do (
  if %i%==!q! set file=%%f
  set /a q+=1
)

echo Filename: %file%
start "" "%file%"
```